# How do I make a div gray out when three checkboxes are checked with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that needs to have a div to fade out when three checkboxes are checked. I am using the code below but it doesn't work. Any suggestions why?

```
<script>
function countChecked() {
var n = $("input:checked").length;
if($("input:checked").length > 3) {

    }
    else
    {
   $(".chkExample")
     .fadeTo(500, 0.2)
    }

}
countChecked();


$(":checkbox").click(countChecked);


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function countChecked() {
    var count = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

    // this will test for 3 or more >=
    if (count >= 3) { alert('3 or more checked!'); }
    else { $(".chkExample").fadeTo(500, 0.2) }
}

countChecked();
// assuming you are using at least 1.7.2 of jQuery
// but start using `.on()` and with checkboxes/radios I always use 'change'
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', countChecked);​
```

On a random side now :checkbox is actually depreciated. Use `[type="checkbox"]` as it will use native javascript to get them faster anyways.

```
​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VR4j6/2/)

Answer (score 3):

I formatted your code a bit.  This is checking for `> 3`.  This would be the same as `>= 4` in this case.  So you are checking for 4 or more, not 3 or more.

If you want exactly 3 boxes checked you need to do `n === 3`. If you want 3 or more use `n >= 3` and for 3 or less use `n <= 3`

Also, if you only want the box checked on a click event, you don't need the manual call to `countChecked`

Also, per the comment, use a local variable to hold the length of your JQuery object.

Also, per mcp's answer, use `[type="checkbox"]` and the `on` method.

**Result:**

```
function countChecked() {
    var n = $("input[type="checkbox"]:checked").length;
    if(n === 3) {
        $(".chkExample").fadeTo(500, 0.2)
    } else {
    }
}
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', countChecked);​
```